# Xcode How to pass preprocess macros with string argument

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm using shell script to build the project.
I wanted to pass string (having spaces, e.g. "Dell Networking") as an argument to `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS`.

I tried following but none of them worked

```
xcodebuild -verbose -sdk macosx10.7 -project TestProject/TestProject.xcodeproj -configuration Release GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS="${PreprocessorArg=$TestArgument}"

xcodebuild -verbose -sdk macosx10.7 -project TestProject/TestProject.xcodeproj -configuration Release GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS=${PreprocessorArg=$TestArgument}
```

I'm getting only first part of the string(e.g. Dell) and that is even without double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TestArgument='Dell Networking'
xcodebuild -verbose -sdk macosx10.7 -project TestProject/TestProject.xcodeproj -configuration Release GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS=${PreprocessorArg="$TestArgument"}
```